# Why the external and internal access for contacts should be same

Tags: community, security, sharing

As per Trailhead module (Link below),

> For contacts, you must set Controlled by Parent for both the default
>   internal and external access.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/communities/modules/community_rollout_impl/units/community_rollout_impl_sharing

Any reason why it has to be always Controlled by Parent?
Any why the default external access level must be more restrictive or equal to the default internal access level.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 4 types of OWD access for contact and let's go one by one with respect to communities.

Private - This should not be applicable for communities where record level sharing are governed by Account and Contact. Here Private means Contact is *not* linked to the Account, regardless of Organizational wise sharing model. *Sharing rules and workflow rules don’t apply to private contacts*.

Controlled by Parent - which is most preferable and should be given. If your organization-wide default for contacts is set to Controlled by Parent, the Contact Access options aren’t available when you share related records such as accounts. Instead, all access to contacts is determined by the user’s access to the contact’s account.

If your organization-wide default for contacts is *Controlled by Parent* and your organization-wide default for accounts is *Private*, you can’t view contacts for accounts that you don’t own, even if you have the *View All* permission on the account object. However, if you own a contact on an account, you can view other contacts on the same account. (Access to a parent account gives you access to the associated child records.)

Public Read Only - Unnecessary exposing user's access for entire organizational Contact has a consequence to the Business.
Secondly, one external user can see other user's record or related to Contact's record (like cases) which we don't want.

See, what community users can do in below image.

[image: Community access]

Public Read Write - which is needless to talk about that.

So, finally it boils down the contact access of external user must be equal to internal user's access (OWD) or restrictive.

Refer [Considerations for Sharing and Accessing Contacts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=contacts_sharing_considerations.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks Santanu. Regarding your first point, if I understood correctly,  you mentioned Private should not be applicable for Community. But as per Trailhead, A best practice is to always have external org-wide defaults set to private. Link: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/community_rollout_impl/units/community_rollout_impl_sharing  And why Sharing rules and workflow rules don’t apply to private contacts?

Comment: Private or Controlled by Parent access should be use case specific and based on the business model. Ideally, contacts are related to Accounts and thats why Private is not a viable solution since we manage access from Account level until and unless it is absolutely necessary for Contact level management. Based on design Salesforce doesn't allow Sharing rules and workflow rules on Private Contacts.